# Iterative function to intercept values by key

Tags: json, typescript

I have a big JSON file that I want to intercept all the values that have the key `text` associated with them, for example:

```
    type":"doc",
   "content":[
      {
         "type":"paragraph",
         "content":[
            {
               "text":"this is a simple page, about a simple umbrella.",
               "type":"text"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "type":"paragraph",
         "content":[
            {
               "text":"you can use this text to find the umbrella page.",
               "type":"text"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "type":"paragraph",
         "content":[
            {
               "text":"do you like it?",
               "type":"text"
            }
         ]
      },
```

I know I can use `Object.keys` but that only covers the "top level" and doesn't go deeper.

I don't wish to use recursion for this, but use an iterative function.

I tried to use `JSON.stringify` but it has poor performance:

```
const obj = JSON.parse(content);
let ret = '';
JSON.stringify(obj, (_, nested) => {
  if (nested && nested[key]) {
    ret += nested[key] + '\n';
  }
  return nested;
});
```

Comment: You could amend the field value already in `JSON.parse` using reviver parameter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter

Answer (score 0):

Not shure that I catch the question, but here is **lodash** solution:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const data = '{"type":"doc","content":[{"type":"paragraph","content":[{"text":"this is a simple page, about a simple umbrella.","type":"text"}]},{"type":"paragraph","content":[{"text":"you can use this text to find the umbrella page.","type":"text"}]},{"type":"paragraph","content":[{"text":"do you like it?","type":"text"}]}]}';

const obj = JSON.parse(data);

const getText = (obj) => {
  const result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    if (key === 'text') acc.push(value);
    if (_.isObject(value)) acc.push(...getText(value));
    if (_.isArray(value)) value.map((item) => getText(item));
    return acc;
  }, []);

  return result;
}

console.log(getText(obj));
// [
//   'this is a simple page, about a simple umbrella.',
//   'you can use this text to find the umbrella page.',
//   'do you like it?'
// ]
```

Comment: You misunderstood me. I want to get an array of values for each value that is next to the key `text`.

Comment: @GilbertWilliams Chenged answer to recursivly get array of `text` values

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to just get the key text, you can use the following method.

```js
var reg = /(?<=\")\w+(?=\"\:)/g
var jsonValue = '{"glossary": {"title": "example glossary","GlossDiv": {"title": "S","GlossList": {"GlossEntry": {"ID": "SGML","SortAs": "SGML","GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language","Acronym": "SGML","Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986","GlossDef": {"para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.","GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]},"GlossSee": "markup"}}}}}';

console.log(jsonValue.match(reg));
```